# UI slider: error: Invalid attached object assignment

Tags: qt, qml

I try to add tooltip to QML slider like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.4
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

// ...

Slider {
    ToolTip: qsTr("This slider likes doing ...") // Invalid attached object assignment

    // ...
}

// ...
```

But I'm receiving this error:

> Invalid attached object assignment

What am I missing?

Comment: did you read the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-tooltip.html#details) before posting the question? what is `ToolTip` here? shouldn't it be `ToolTip.text` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error got resolved by using `ToolTip` this way:

```
Slider {
    ToolTip {
        text: qsTr("This slider likes doing ...")
        visible: parent.hovered
        delay: 1000
    }
}
```